# fixed and setprecision in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float c = 5.0;
    float far = (9/5)*c + 32;
    cout << fixed << "Temperature in Fahrenheit is "<< setprecision(2) << 
    far;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be 41.00, but the actual output is 37.00.

Comment: You could change the order of evaluation to `c * 9 / 5`. The expression is evaluated left to right and types are converted to float at each step.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `9` and `5` are `int`s and hence `9/5` results in `int` `1`.

Your code operates on `float`s and needs a `float` multiplier for the conversion to work correctly. So a fix would be to define the multiplier as `9.f / 5` (`.` is a shorthand notation for `.0` exponent, `f` suffix designates a `float` literal, see [floating point literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) for more details), e.g.:

```
float far = (9.f / 5) * c + 32;
```

Comment: Changing the order of eavluation to `c * 9 / 5` will also work.

Comment: @MarkoMahnič That is true, however, `(9.f/5)` is calculated at compile time and replaced with a constant. Whereas `c * 9 / 5` has to be evaluated as written at run-time due to non-associativity of floating point operations, i.e. `(c*9.f)/5 != c*(9.f/5)`

Answer (score 1):

since 9/5 is in brackets, divison will happen first which results to 1. so 1*5+32 = 37